Can you add a custom domain to an app in an internal Azure Container App environment
I can successfully add a custom domain on external container app environments. But when I try the same on an app in an internal container app environment, the validation process just hangs (More than 12 hours now). I have confirmed that the requisite DNS records have been added correctly. This is where it gets stuck:

The docs state that if you are using a free managed cert, then your container app environment has to be publicly accessible. I'm bringing my own cert which does not seem to have any such requirement.
Is it possible to add a custom domain to an internal Azure Container App environment?

Yes, it is possible to add a custom domain to an internal Azure Container App environment. However, additional configuration is required to use custom domains with VNET-scope ingress. The validation process may hang if the requisite DNS records have not been added correctly. The docs state that if you are using a free managed cert, then your container app environment has to be publicly accessible. However, if you are bringing your own cert, there is no such requirement.


Custom domain names and free managed certificates in Container Apps (azure-portal)
Custom domain names and bring your own certificates in Azure Container Apps
Custom domain names & free managed certificates in Container Apps (azure-cli)


@Arko I've found that when using an external ACA environment, the validation errors with a message that the records are not correctly setup. Can you elaborate on what "additional configuration" is required?

When adding a custom domain to an ACA, Azure typically requires the creation of one or more DNS records to prove domain ownership and to route traffic correctly such as CNAME Record then TXT Record. Log into your DNS provider's management console.Verify that the CNAME and TXT records exist and are correctly pointed as instructed by Azure. Use DNS lookup tools to confirm that your DNS changes have propagated and are visible externally. Tools like nslookup, dig, or online services like DNS Checker can help. If DNS records are correctly set up, then check network config and Azure policies.

I have done created the records and can confirm through dig that they have been added correctly, as mentioned in the original question.

It turns out there is additional configuration required for internal environments:

If you are using an internal Container Apps environment, there is no validation for the DNS binding, as the cluster can only be accessed from within the virtual network. Additionally, create a private DNS zone that resolves the apex domain to the static IP address of the Container Apps environment. You can use Azure Private DNS or your own DNS server. If you use Azure Private DNS, create a Private DNS Zone named as the apex domain, with an A record that points to the static IP address of the Container Apps environment.

Source
Note that even after doing this I still could not validate ownership through the portal. So I used the cli to add the domain:
az containerapp hostname add --hostname <custom domain> -n <container app name> -g <resource group>

This adds the domain but you still have to bind a cert to it, which I was able to do through the portal. Just choose "Custom Domains" from your container app and click "bind" on the domain you just added.
